# Move Text Down in Table to Avoid Overlap with Line

Tags: tables, multirow, multicolumn

I'd like to move the text "District Profile Report: English Language Learners" down so that it doesn't touch the upper horizontal line while keeping the logo aligned between the two lines (the logo will replace the green rectangle).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[top=0.75in, bottom=0.75in, left=0.5in, right=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{array} % for centering text in tables
\usepackage{multirow} % for having multiple rows merged in tables
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

% Create new command called Cline for thick line in tables
\newlength{\Oldarrayrulewidth}
\newcommand{\Cline}[2]{%
  \noalign{\global\setlength{\Oldarrayrulewidth}{\arrayrulewidth}}%
  \noalign{\global\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{#1}}\cline{#2}%
  \noalign{\global\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{\Oldarrayrulewidth}}}

\begin{document}
\SweaveOpts{concordance=TRUE}


\begin{table}[h]
\begin{tabular}{m{2.5cm} m{5.75cm} m{4.75cm} b{3.75cm}} % Creates columns of specified width
\Cline{2pt}{2-4} % Creates a horizontal line from cell two to four
\multirow{2}{*}{\includegraphics[width=2.5cm]{DPIlogo_SS}} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\Large\textbf{District Profile Report: English Language Learners}}\\[0.6cm]
& \textbf{District: Example District} & \textbf{District Code: 0001} & \textbf{School Year: 2013-14}\\
\Cline{2pt}{2-4} % Creates a horizontal line from cell two to four
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image: Example of Line and Text Overlap]

Answer (score 3):

Don't reinvent the wheel: you'll have a simpler code with the `booktabs` package. It lets you specify the rule width as an optional argument, and you can set vertical spacing around horizontal lines with the `\aboverulesep` and `\belowrulesep` lengths. The (lr)  argument specify a (customisable) trimming space at the left and right of a `\cmidrule`. In addition, you can use the `\addlinespace[…]` command. as I don't see why this should float, I deleted the ` table environment:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage[top=0.75in, bottom=0.75in, left=0.5in, right=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{array, booktabs} % for centering text in tables
\usepackage{multirow} % for having multiple rows merged in tables
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\setlength\aboverulesep{0.75ex}
\setlength\belowrulesep{1.25ex}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{m{2.5cm} m{5.75cm} m{4.75cm} b{3.75cm}} % Creates columns of specified width
\cmidrule[2pt]{2-4} % Creates a horizontal line from cell two to four
 \multirow{2}{*}{\includegraphics[width=2.5cm]{DPIlogo_SS}} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\Large\textbf{District Profile Report: English Language Learners}}\\[0.6cm]
& \textbf{District: Example District} & \textbf{District Code: 0001} & \textbf{School Year: 2013-14}\\
\cmidrule[2pt]{2-4} % Creates a horizontal line from cell two to four
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The `table` environment should be left out: this seems a header, so just `\noindent` before `\begin{tabular]` is what's needed.

Comment: @egreg: I had n't thought about that, but for sure, it doesn't have any caption and I don't see whay it should float.